# How to modify a toString method of an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, tostring

I'm trying to modify a toString method in my Warehouse class so that it will return

```
Bin B0:
Dress Shoe - Loafer (size 10-1/2), SKU 1234-13: 5
Boot - Riding (size 8), SKU 1234-5: 5
Bin B1:
Bin B2:
Dress Shoe - Wing-tip (size 10), SKU 1234-3: 10
Bin B3:
Casual Shoe - Sandal (size 9-1/2), SKU 1234-0: 8
Bin B4:
```

from my main class

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
  Warehouse w = new Warehouse( 10 );
  Footwear d0 = new DressShoe( "Loafer", 10.5, "1234-13" );
  Footwear b = new Boot( "Riding", 8, "1234-5" );
  Footwear c = new CasualShoe( "Sandal", 9.5, "1234-0" );
  Footwear d1 = new DressShoe( "Wing-tip", 10, "1234-3" );
  w.stockWarehouse( d0, 5, "B0" );
  w.stockWarehouse( b, 5, "B0" );
  w.stockWarehouse( c, 8, "B3" );
  w.stockWarehouse( d1, 10, "B2" );
  System.out.println( w.toString() );
}
```

The stockWarehouse method is "hidden" and not given. DressShoe, Boot, CasualShoe, and DressShoe are extended classes of Footwear.

Footwear is a class that takes in String style, double size, and String SKU. Its toString method returns the shoe info such as:

```
Dress Shoe - Loafer (size 10-1/2), SKU 1234-13
```

Bin is a class that takes in String name and creates an ArrayList of contents, Its toString method returns the Bin number and the contents such as:

```
[SKU 1234-13: 5, SKU 1234-13: 5]
```

This is my Warehouse class.

```
public class Warehouse {
    private int myBinMax;
    private ArrayList<Footwear> myCatalog;
    private ArrayList<Bin> myBins;

    public Warehouse (int binMax)
    {
        myBinMax = binMax;
        myCatalog = new ArrayList<Footwear>();
        myBins = new ArrayList<Bin>(5);
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
        {
            addBin();
        }
    }

    public void addBin() 
    { 
       myBins.add( new Bin( "B" + myBins.size() ) );
    }

    @override
    public String toString()
    {
      String b0 = myBins.get(0).getName() + "\n" + 
      myCatalog.get(0).toString() + ", " +   myBins.get(0).getContents().get(1) + "\n";

    int b0size = myBins.get(0).getContents().size();

    return b0size + b0;
    }       
}
```

*EDIT* added footwear class

```
public class Footwear

{

private String myStyle;
private double mySize;
private String mySKU; 

public Footwear ( String style, double size, String SKU)

{
    myStyle = style;
    mySize = size;
    mySKU = SKU;
}


 public String getStyle()

 {
     return myStyle;
 }


 public double getSize()

 {
     return mySize;
 }


 public String getSKU()

 {
     return mySKU;
 }


 public String getType()

 {
     return "Unspecified";
 }

 public String printSize()

 {
     int x = (int)(getSize());
     if (getSize() % x == 0.5)
     return getStyle() + " (size " + x + "-1/2)";  

     else
     return getStyle() + " (size " + x + ")";

 }

 public String toString()

 {
      int x = (int)(getSize());
      String ShoeInfo = "";
      if (getSize() % x == 0.5)
      ShoeInfo = getStyle() + " (size " + x + "\u00bd" + ")";
      else
      ShoeInfo= getStyle() + " (size " + x + ")";    

     if (!(getType().equals("Unspecified")))
     return getType() + " - " + ShoeInfo;

     else
     return ShoeInfo;

 }

}
```

Comment: Can you show the code of Bin class?

Comment: For the toString, you add the bits you need in the order you need them.  There is no magic going on to make that happen.

Comment: @Eran, sure I've added the Bin class.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I've tried but I can't find a way to make the Bins# from the stockWareHouse method to match the Bins# from myBins

Comment: The problems seems to be in your`BinItem's toString()`method and in your Warehouse's`toString()`. I personally can't understand how you want to display all of your BINS, when you only use the index 0:  `int x = 0;
 binsOut = myBins.get(x).toString();
 catOut = myCatalog.get(x).toString();`

Comment: It's not clear what's the relation between myCatalog list and myBins list, but if Bin's toString doesn't return the output you need for Warehouse's toString, jsut don't use it. You can access the properties of the Bin instance (with getName and getContents) and format them however you need.

Comment: @Eran I'll try it like that. I tried `myBins.get(0).getContents()` and it returns `[SKU 1234-13: 5, SKU 1234-5: 5]` Is there a way to separate these two to match myCatalog?

Comment: `myBins.get(0).getContents().get(i)` will return the i'th element of the list.

Comment: You have failed to show your BinItem class and how the information is stored there.  You are also using a class with an ArrayList referencing another class with yet another arraylist using a class you have yet to reveal to us.  You may want to think of a different way of storing your data.

Comment: @DavidColer I added the BinItem class. No, I can't choose a different way of storing my data, I coded these according to instructions.

Comment: please post the bin class back into the question.

Comment: as well as the stockWharehouse function and anything else you are doing with these classes.

Comment: okay I think I found your solution, you need to use the binout to get the correct show type string from the footwear catalog.  using the sku or some other identifier, that way when you output each bin no matter how many items are in it, it will reference to the footwear instead of trying to get strings from both and adding them together.

Comment: I solved your problem below please look at the solution and mark it if it works for you, which It should

Comment: Thank you! Haven't checked the website in a couple days, sorry for not responding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your solution
new Warehouse toString method

```
@Override
    public String toString()
    {
      String output = "";
      for(Bin b : myBins)
      {
          System.out.print(b.toString());
          if(!b.getContents().isEmpty())
          {
            for(BinItem bi : b.getContents())
            {
                System.out.println(findSKU(bi.getSKU()) + ", " + bi.toString());
            }
          }
      }
      return " ";
    }   
    private String findSKU(String SKU)
    {
        for(Footwear f : myCatalog)
        {
            if(SKU.equals(f.getSKU()))
                return f.toString();
        }
        return "";
    }
```

new Bin toString method

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
    String s = "Bin " + myName + ":\n";
    return s;    
}
```

To complete this you need to add another variable to the footwear class called String shoeType and have the subclasses of footwear set it to the corresponding type IE Dress Shoe, Casual Shoe

new Footwear toString Method

```
@Override
    public String toString()
    {
        int x = (int)(getSize());
        String ShoeInfo = "";
        if (getSize() % x == 0.5)
            ShoeInfo = shoeType + " - " + myStyle + " (size " + x + "\u00bd" + ")";
        else
            ShoeInfo= shoeType + " - " + myStyle + " (size " + x + ")";    
         if (!(getType().equals("Unspecified")))
            return getType() + " - " + ShoeInfo;
         else
            return ShoeInfo;
    }
```

Sample output with above changes.

```
Bin B0:
Dress Shoe - Loafer (size 10½), SKU 1234-13: 5
Boot - Riding (size 8), SKU 1234-5: 5
Bin B1:
Bin B2:
Dress Shoe - Wing-tip (size 10), SKU 1234-3: 10
Bin B3:
Casual Shoe - Sandal (size 9½), SKU 1234-0: 8
Bin B4:
Bin B5:
Bin B6:
Bin B7:
Bin B8:
Bin B9:
```

Comment: I've added the footwear class at the bottom. I tried this and gave me an error "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 4"

Comment: your bin array list is smaller.. however your footwear could be the one causing the problem.  this is an interesting conundrum.

Comment: This is great, thank you so much! I've been working on this little project for days and I actually gave up today... Just checked and saw that you've updated it!

One thing I'd like to add is that I couldn't override my Bin and Footwear methods and could only edit the Warehouse class. I revised the bin name printout to     `System.out.print(b.getName()+ ":" + "\n"); `
Once again, thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this problem using the StringBuilder Class in your Warehouse class. This class allows for string manipulations such as appends, inserts, and removals.

Here is the PSUEDO-CODE that should get you on the right track

```
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
output.append(myBins.get(x).toString());
ouput.replace(0, output.length, "/n");
int colon = output.charAt(':');
output.insert(colon, "/n");
output.insert(colon +1, catOut);
```

You may need to tweek it, but this should give you the idea